# Mongoose automatically inserts '$in' on queries for [Mixed]-Arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently, when I query for a document containing properties with mixed-datatyle by using an array in a query, the array-objects are not taken as-is, but the array is automatically put in an $in-clause as seen in the example below. If I don't use schema.Types.Mixed, the query works as expected. 
What is the reason for this and how can I disable this feature without having to manually define my schema?

Here's an example of this behaviour, copied from my post on a (potentially) related ticket on the github issues: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8202

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const GITHUB_ISSUE = `8202`;
const connectionString = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${GITHUB_ISSUE}`;
const { Schema, SchemaTypes } = mongoose;

run()
  .then(() => console.log('done'))
  .catch(error => console.error(error.stack));

async function run() {
  await mongoose.connect(connectionString);
  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
  // if we manually define the schema like this it'll work as expected:
  // validations: [{a:String}]
  const TestSchema = new Schema({ validations: Schema.Types.Mixed });
  const TestModel = mongoose.model(GITHUB_ISSUE, TestSchema);

  // creating testObject
  let test1 = new TestModel({ validations: [{ a: 'b' }, { a: 'a' }] });
  await test1.save();

  /*
    The output of mongoose.debug will look like this:
    Mongoose: indextests.count({
    validations:
      {
        '$in': [
          { a: 'b' },
          { a: 'THIS SHOULD NOT BE FOUND' }
        ]
      }
    }, {})
  */
  const count = await TestModel.count({ validations: [{ a: 'b' }, { a: 'THIS SHOULD NOT BE FOUND' }] })
  if (count === 1) {
    // This will be the output
    console.log('----> Error, count should be 0, not 1!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is fine!')
  }

  process.exit();
}
```

As you can see, the query of course returns a value, even though I would expect it to not find anything.

P.S.: Yeah, count() will be deprecated, but that is not the point.

Comment: Refer to the source code, if the filter is an array and the field is not Array or Buffer type then mongoose will put in an `$in`.

Comment: Thanks @CuongLeNgoc, could you give me a link to the file?

Comment: You can check here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/9a1d494141a482d2923ac7f2224b80886bc2b6e8/lib/cast.js#L296

Comment: Perfect, thank you @CuongLeNgoc! I am still wondering why this is the preferred behaviour, but at least I now know a little more about the implementation!